# Sikuli RNG script repeating the same number

Tags: python, sikuli

When I use the  type(str(num)) for random numbers I get the same one over and over: 510304296165725

I'm not sure why it keeps repeating since the parameters are set before the script starts to loop. I can't get the code to fit right, but it is indented properly.

```
running = True
def runHotkey(event):
    global running
    running = False
import random
num = random.randrange(000000000000000,999999999999999)
Env.addHotkey(Key.F1, KeyModifier.CTRL, runHotkey)

while exists(Pattern("1495843225731.png").similar(0.10)) and running:


    if exists(Pattern("1541289046943.png").similar(0.71)):
  DoubleClick(Pattern("1541289689152.png").similar(0.90).targetOffset(-39,3))
        wait(1)
        type(str(num))        
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)

else:
    wait(1)
    click(Pattern("1541289841740.png").similar(0.82))
    wait(1)
    type("1.wav")
    type(Key.ENTER)
```

Comment: You start by `running = False` so how is your code entering the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! The script would identify a random number to use for the given loop before it ran.  I placed the import random number at the start of the loop and it generates a new one each time.  Thanks for the help.. here it is:

```
running = True
def runHotkey(event):
    global running
    running = False
Env.addHotkey(Key.F1, KeyModifier.CTRL, runHotkey)

while exists(Pattern("1495843225731.png").similar(0.10)) and running:
    import random
    num = random.randrange(000000000000000,999999999999999)



if exists(Pattern("1541289046943.png").similar(0.71)):
    doubleClick(Pattern("1541289689152.png").similar(0.90).targetOffset(-39,3))
    wait(1)
    type(str(num))        
    type(Key.ENTER)
    wait(1)

else:
    wait(1)
    click(Pattern("1541289841740.png").similar(0.82))
    wait(1)
    type("1.wav")
    type(Key.ENTER)
```